# Fragment Loses Data on Return Not Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-fragments, restore, android-listfragment, android-lifecycle

I have Activity A and Fragment A (ListFragment). On click the flow goes to Activity B and Fragment B.

When on Activity/Fragment A the list data is saved in `onSaveInstanceState` (using a parcelable arraylist) and works fine for orientation changes. When going to Activity/Fragment B the state is saved however I can't figure out how to restore the state when going back.

None of the lifecycle events where state can be restored seem to be called.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmmmm you don't need to restore the state unless your activity is killed, which shouldn't be when going to another activity. It MIGHT get killed if it's hidden for a while, but at that point you'll get the onSaveInstanceState call. If you're losing state you might be resetting something in onResume() needlessly.

Comment: I don't use onResume, i don't replace anything in onStart...

Comment: You should post FragmentA code.